# Redirect website but maintain my url in browser address bar

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache2

While our new website is under development we want to allow a small user base to look at the new site and get feedback. Our current site www.sitea.com will remain functional and available but we want them to visit www.sitea.com/v2 and have the browser maintain the url www.sitea.com/v2 but show the contents of the new site www.siteb.com is this possible?

Preferably this would be done with an .htaccess file if possible I am open to other suggestions though.

Comment: How do you determine who "them" is?

Comment: What did you tried so far ?

Comment: @JonLin I guess, the OP just gives the new URL away to some of their users.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, you can use [`ProxyPass`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) for this

> This directive allows remote servers to be mapped into the space of the local server.

I haven't used this myself, but something like this might work

```
<Location "/v2/">
    ProxyPass "http://www.siteb.com/"
</Location>
```

Unfortunately, this cannot be used in a .htaccess file. The [Context](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/directive-dict.html#Context) lists only

> Context: server config, virtual host, directory

See the manual for details.