# Redirect subdomain into a folder of another domain

Tags: .htaccess, dns, subdomain, hosting

I'm trying to redirect one subdomain (a wordpress.com domain) into a folder of another domain. Example:

```
blog.domain.com to anotherdomain.com/blog
```

I know that is possible by using .htacces files, but i dont have a hosting service on my first domain.

Is it possible to do it by using DNS?

I have tried by creating some A and CNAME registrations but I cant find a way to do it: Can I have a ip for a specific folder of my second domain?

Thanks :)

Comment: As it happens, I just answered a similar question. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/32968677/1741542

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I attempted to do a comment but it's too much. You can do this if you own both domains. If you don't have hosting on the first domain but you do on the `other domain`, then you can add the main domain as an `ServerAlias` on the other server.

Either through your control panel or your vhost config do the following.

1. Add an A record for `blog.domain.com` in DNS pointing to the IP address of the other domain with the hosting account.
2. In the configuration of the web server with the hosting add a [ServerAlias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#serveralias) of `blog.domain.com` to the `anotherdomain.com` vhost config.
3. in the root of the `anotherdomain.com` put this code inside your .htaccess file.

If you want it to actually redirect then you can do this

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://anotherdomain.com/blog/$1 [R=301,L]
```

If you don't want it to redirect and keep blog.domain.com in the address bar then, you can do this.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^blog\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /blog/$1 [L]
```

Comment: what did you end up doing?

Comment: Ok cool. Glad it worked for you. Be sure to accept the answer. Thx